# Can't include OpenBR library file in project file

Tags: qt, opencv

Warning: I'm no Qt expert, so that may be what my problem is.

I built OpenBR on Windows 7 with MinGW following [this guide](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/windows_mingw.html).

This results in `libopenbr.dll` and the Unix-style `libopenbr.dll.a`.

What do I need to do in my `.pro` file to add it to my project?  I've added the library path  with:

```
LIBS += -L"include/openbr/lib"
```

That does not produce any errors.  But I can't get the project to acknowledge the existence of the library in that location.

For the library itself, again, named `libopenbr.dll.a`, I've tried:

```
LIBS += -lopenbr
```

and

```
LIBS += -lopenbr.dll
```

and

```
LIBS += libopenbr.dll.a
```

and a number of other random guesses, but it never sees the file.

What am I doing wrong?  I don't normally think of myself as an idiot, but after being stumped by what should be a pretty easy task, I'm starting to wonder.

Comment: Didn't it generated a libopenbr.lib ?

Comment: Just the `libopenbr.dll.a` file and the `libopenbr.dll` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this when I tagged the OpenBR 0.3 release, and I couldn't reproduce the issue. Here's what worked for me: [QMake Integration](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/qmake_integration.html)

Having said that, there was a tricky part for me in setting up Qt Creator properly with MinGW. By default it was configured to find my Visual Studio installation. I fixed this by tinkering with my manual kit `Tools->Options->Build & Run->Manual Desktop (default)`. In particular:

```
Compiler = MinGW (x86 64bit in C:\mingw64\bin)
Debugger = GDB Engine using "C:\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe"
Qt Version = Qt 5.0.2 (mingw64)
```

From what I experienced, if these aren't set correctly qmake will look for .lib files instead of .dll.a files when linking. My suspicion is that this will be made easier in Qt 5.1 when MinGW_w64 gets first class support by Qt.